# How to use the google drive api without allowing users to install chrome webstore apps?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps

I've made a drive application that does some actions with files inside a google apps domain. To use the drive api in an apps domain I had to put allow users to install webstore apps on. But I don't really want users to install chrome webstore apps.

**Is there a possibility to allow users to use the drive api within our domain without allowing them to install Webstore apps?**

This is the error I get when it's off :

403 The domain policy has disabled third-party Drive apps.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an installation issue, this is a domain issue. Your domain administrator needs to enable third party Drive Apps in their CPanel.

Once you have done that, you can request the install scope to install an application, there is no requirement on Chrome Webstore integration.

Comment: But can't he only allow our own applications without allowing everything?

Comment: I looked at this but it doesn't seem to support drive apps. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/manifest#example

Comment: I never request the install scope? Its a webserver application that I've made.

Comment: ditto problem here. User has signed up for our web app (http://openera.com) from a google apps domain.  Connecting to GDrive via oauth authentication is successful but accessing the api with the resuting tokens tosses the "Get Files Error: [403] The domain policy has disabled third-party Drive apps ". To be clear, the user is not, and has not added a 3rdParty app to the domain (we have not built one).