# What does "403 The domain policy has disabled third-party Drive apps" mean?

Tags: google-drive-api

I've read [How to use the google drive api without allowing users to install chrome webstore apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233791/how-to-use-the-google-drive-api-without-allowing-users-to-install-chrome-webstor) , the only answer to which talks about "installing".

So, does this message mean that all access to the Drive API is blocked, thus my app can't be used? or does it mean that my app can be used, but it can't be installed into the Drive UI?

Answer (score 0):

If you're a Google Apps user, your admin can disable the app installation to user's individual Drives. You need to enable it in order to implement create/open with flows.

Comment: so, you're saying that the restriction ONLY applies to the create/open flows from the Drive UI, and that all other Drive SDK API operations (create, delete, etc) from my app will work fine, even though the admin has disabled third party apps?